# Is there a way to mint several ENS at the same time?

Tags: transactions, ether, mint, ens

I'm looking to mint 2 [ENS](https://ens.domains/fr/) at the same time to avoid paying the fee twice.
Is that something possible ?

Have a wonderful day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not affiliated but [ens.vision](https://www.ens.vision/) has a bulk registration feature. It claims to save up to 30% gas, but they charge a fee of 20%. In their [faq](https://www.ens.vision/faq), it says it works by:

`Our bulk register contract is using the ENS contract function register() and not registerWithConfig() that the ENS dApp uses by default to mint names. registerWithConfig() sets the default resolver for a name in the same transaction. register() does not set the default resolver for a name in the same transaction.`

Answer (score 0):

The ENS bulk registration feature has been enabled on [NameApes.com](https://NameApes.com) You may now register a list of domains in a single transaction to save time and gas fees.

These are the costs of different registrations for comparison:

1. Register 1 name via app.ens.domains: 0.01547 Ξ
2. Register 1 name via nameapes.com: 0.01430 Ξ (~1% cheaper)
3. Register 10 names via app.ens.domains: 0.1323 Ξ
4. Register 10 names via nameapes.com: 0.1161 Ξ (~13% cheaper)
5. Register 10 names via nameapes.com without resolver: 0.0803 Ξ (40%
   cheaper)

Reference: https://blog.ensdom.com/blog/bulk-search-register-available-ens-names